# Mongo-atlas connection : ReferenceError: client is not defined

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

when trying to connect to the mongo atlas I'm getting the error "ReferenceError: client is not defined".

> Console's erro :
>
> const db = client.db('coneccao-teste');
>               ReferenceError: client is not defined

See below my NodeJs code with the configuration of the Express server and mongo-atlas connection.

Have you sugestion ?

thanks!

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
const port = 3000;
const mongo_uri = 'mongodb+srv://rbk:******-@cluster0-5zvdy.mongodb.net/coneccao-teste?retryWrites=true';
const db = client.db('coneccao-teste');
const collection = db.collection('inicio');


MongoClient.connect(mongo_uri, { useNewUrlParser: true })
.then(client => {
  const db = client.db('coneccao-teste');
  const collection = db.collection('inicio');
  app.listen(port, () => console.info(`REST API running on port ${port}`));
}).catch(error => console.error(error));

// add this line before app.listen()
app.locals.collection = collection;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const collection = req.app.locals.collection;
  collection.find({}).toArray().then(response => res.status(200).json(response)).catch(error => console.error(error));
});

app.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
  const collection = req.app.locals.collection;
  const id = new ObjectId(req.params.id);
  collection.findOne({ _id: id }).then(response => res.status(200).json(response)).catch(error => console.error(error));
});


app.listen(port);
```

Comment: Try removing lines 8 and 9 of your snippet... you copied them to the callback but didn't remove them from the 'global' context

Comment: Thank @Rondo! But I'm getting a new error : ** app.locals.collection = collection; ReferenceError: collection is not defined ** . Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regarding your second problem the collection is just not defined.

when you declare:

```
app.locals.collection = collection;
```

your mongo connection has probably not connected yet meaning that collection is undefined at that point

insert this declaration after the connection is established and before you start listening with ur app:

```
MongoClient.connect(mongo_uri, { useNewUrlParser: true })
.then(client => {
  const db = client.db('coneccao-teste');
  const collection = db.collection('inicio');
  app.locals.collection = collection;
  app.listen(port, () => console.info(`REST API running on port ${port}`));
}).catch(error => console.error(error));
```

now the collection is guaranteed to be defined the way you expect it to be when starting your app.

Comment: . Great ! The problem was solved. Have a nice day ! : D